# Ubuntu 12.10 won't save display settings after reboot . How do I fix this?

Tags: 12.10, wubi, display, settings, reboot

When I mean display settings I mean desktop backgrounds or icons that I removed from the Unity launcher. It just goes back to the default every reboot. The only thing it did save is the theme that I changed. I installed Ubuntu with Wubi.